# How to deal with "The ID '...' is already used by another control when conditionally removing controls?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a custom control that currently conditionally renders content:

```
<me:CustomControl>
    <switch>
        <if "expression is true">
            <textbox id="Name" />
        </if>
        <if "expression is true">
            ...
        </if>
        <else>
            <textbox id="Name" />
        </else>
    </switch>
</me:CustomControl>
```

My example above makes no logical sense, but gets straight to the point. The `<if>` tag is evaluated by overriding the `GetChildControlType` function. The `<textbox>` inside is evaluated in the `<if>`'s control builder.

What I want to do is completely remove the control from the collection, or even better yet, prevent child controls of `<if>` from being added to the collection to begin with. If I try to remove them OnInit, I still get the error **"The ID 'Name' is already used by another control."**

I can't evaluate them in the:

```
Public Overrides Function GetChildControlType(ByVal tagName... ) As Type
```

Because I need to perform logic on all the if's and else's within it.

Maybe there's a better way?

**Update**

I get a compilation error even if I break this thing down to bare bones if there are more than one controls with the same ID, even though overriding `CreateChildControls`. not sure if I can get around this at all.

Comment: Good question, but yes, that's the way it is. You simply can't have more than one element with the same ID in an XML document, even if one is inside an `if` element and the other isn't. No idea how to solve this though.

Comment: Based on condition add those controls dynamically or instead of trying to remove the control, update the same control with properties based on conditions, again dynamically